# sorting index of vector of vector based on size

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a vector of vectors and I want to sort it by the size of each vector. I want to put the index of the sorting vector in another vector and I don't want to change the main vector.
how could I do that?
I want to use the sort function but I can't find any parameter in the sort function that determines I want to sort it with the size of each content and store index.

I try this but it has an error.

In sort_tree I store indexes from 0 to n-1(n is the size of the 2D array)

and the tree is my 2D array.

```
std::sort(sort_tree.begin(), sort_tree.end(),
          [](const int & a, const int& b, vector<vector<int>> tree) {
              return tree[a].size() < tree[b].size();
          });
```

The error is:

`Error   C2228   left of '.size' must have class/struct/union`

I think it because of the third argument.

Comment: What error? [Edit] to quote it in full.

Comment: What is `tree`? Where should it be supplied from? Do you perhaps want to use lambda capture to refer to it, instead of passing a 3rd argument that `std::sort()` can't handle?

Comment: Try `std::sort(sort_tree.begin(), sort_tree.end(),[&tree](const int & a, const int& b) { return tree[a].size() < tree[b].size();});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a sort table based on the content of another container requires either a custom functor or a capturing lambda. The latter is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tree;

    // fill tree with whatever

    // build index table.
    std::vector<int> idx(tree.size());
    std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

    // sort with capturing lambda
    std::sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [&tree](int lhs, int rhs)
    {
        return tree[lhs].size() < tree[rhs].size();
    });
}
```